# Why does my bathroom mirror distort so much?

Tags: materials, glass, reflection

I am trying to make the mirror in this bathroom scene extracted from a video game have proper full reflections, but I can't for the life of me figure what settings to use in the shader. I've tried the obvious stuff: Roughness 0, Transmission 1, Metallic 1, and different combinations of the three. But the problem is, even when I get clear, opaque reflections to appear, they're extremely distorted and look super unnatural. My mesh is is single flat plane, so I'm confused as to why the reflection is being distorted. I thought it might be Index of Refraction, but changing that seems to do nothing at all, even when set to extreme values like 0.0001 or 50.

In this screenshot, I am using a Principled BSDF shader with Metallic 1 and Roughness 0. This is as little distortion as am I able to achieve and as you can see there is still a lot of warping going on the mirror. Why is this happening?[image]

Comment: It’s the index of reflection I guess. Instead of a Principled BSDF use a Diffuse and a Glossy BSDF, mixed together with a Mix Shader and Fresnel with IOR of 1.0 as factor.

Comment: Are you using Smooth or Flat shading? Looks to me as a problem with the Normal of the mirror.

Comment: @RichSedman Could you post this as answer, since it apparently solved the problem.

Comment: @RobertGutzkow - now posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflective and refractive surfaces are very dependent on the surface Normal. Make sure the Normal is pointing in the right direction (outwards) and that the surface is set to Smooth or Flat shading as appropriate (in this case it should be Flat).

Comment: "Bathroom mirror making you look fat? Try this one weird trick... Maya users HATE him!"

Answer (score 3):

It was the Normals facing the wrong direction!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112510)

Comment: Hey @RobertGützkow :). Rich didn't post an answer yet, only a comment.

Comment: @JachymMichal Whoops, only saw the answer in review and didn't check. My bad.